# foreach in json decode not working

Tags: php, json, decode

I want to get key and values from a json string like below

**JSON :**

```
[{
    "EXTAPP_ID": "9901",
    "CATEGORY_ID": "10",
    "LANGUAGE_CODE": "tr",
    "CATEGORY_LANG_DESC": "Sat\u0131\u015f Departman\u0131"
}, {
    "EXTAPP_ID": "9901",
    "CATEGORY_ID": "10",
    "LANGUAGE_CODE": "de",
    "CATEGORY_LANG_DESC": "Sales Abteilung"
}, {
    "EXTAPP_ID": "9901",
    "CATEGORY_ID": "20",
    "LANGUAGE_CODE": "de",
    "CATEGORY_LANG_DESC": "Procurement Abteilung"
}, {
    "EXTAPP_ID": "9901",
    "CATEGORY_ID": "20",
    "LANGUAGE_CODE": "tr",
    "CATEGORY_LANG_DESC": "Sat\u0131nalma Departman\u0131"
}, {
    "EXTAPP_ID": "9901",
    "CATEGORY_ID": "10",
    "LANGUAGE_CODE": "en",
    "CATEGORY_LANG_DESC": "Sales Department"
}, {
    "EXTAPP_ID": "9901",
    "CATEGORY_ID": "20",
    "LANGUAGE_CODE": "en",
    "CATEGORY_LANG_DESC": "Procurement Department"
}]
```

**PHP :**

```
$string = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
foreach($string as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . " : " . $value;
}
```

**it returns**

```
0 : Array1 : Array2 : Array3 : Array4 : Array5 : Array
```

Comment: `$string` is a really poor choice of variable name for a decoded array. The one thing we can be fairly sure that `$string` isn't is a string.

Comment: That aside, the problem is that you're looping through the top level of the decoded array, but ignoring the fact that it's a multi-level structure. Try using `print_r($value)` instead of your `echo` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that output because your JSON has an array of objects (which PHP is parsing as an array of arrays). You need a nested loop:

```
foreach($string AS $array) {
    foreach($array AS $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " : " . $value;
    }
}
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/Ee1iF

Answer (score 0):

You're  returning an array of objects not values. You need to parse that object like :

```
foreach($string as $object) {
      foreach($object as $key => $value) {
          echo "Key :" .$key;
          echo "Value :" . $value;
       }
}
```